# here document with HTML not identifying delimiter

Tags: php, html, heredoc

What is supposed to happen when there is HTML in a here document?
Isn't it supposed to just be stored as a string?
The HTML in this screen is displayed on screen and so is the delimiter "HTMLBLOCK;" portion of the code. What is going on?

```
<? php
<<<HTMLBLOCK
<html>
<head><title>Menu</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#fffed9">
<h1>Dinner</h1>
<ul>
<li>Beef Chow-Mun</li>
<li>Sauteed Pea Shoots</li>
<li>Soy Sauce Noodles</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
HTMLBLOCK;
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Dinner

Beef Chow-Mun

Sauteed Pea Shoots

Soy Sauce Noodles

HTMLBLOCK; ?>
```

Comment: The space in `<? php` is wrong. The rest looks fine.

Comment: A good way to debug these problems is to view the source in your browser. You'll see your PHP in there verbatim, because the web server has not processed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP does have a wrong syntax on the top with: `<? php`. There should be no space there. Instead of doing that, you could `echo` the HTML content with PHP; or you can close out of PHP and write out the PHP then open PHP tags again:

```
echo '<html>
    <head><title>Menu</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="#fffed9">
        <h1>Dinner</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Beef Chow-Mun</li>
            <li>Sauteed Pea Shoots</li>
            <li>Soy Sauce Noodles</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>';
```

Or you could do this:

```
<?php
// .. PHP code here .. 
?>
<html>
    <head><title>Menu</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="#fffed9">
        <h1>Dinner</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Beef Chow-Mun</li>
            <li>Sauteed Pea Shoots</li>
            <li>Soy Sauce Noodles</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
// ..code continues..
?>
```

You could also store the HTML in a variable and `echo the variable.